# Can I use jquery and AJAX to call a cgi-bin script, then add message event to handle Server Sent Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, server-sent-events

What I have is a long running cgi-bin program (runs for 3-15 minutes) that I want to call using AJAX.   While its running, I'd like to receive Server Sent Event data from it and display it on my web page.  Kinda like a progress monitor -  but more like a chat window that is updated automatically as the script runs.

Here's how I'm calling the script:

`var Params = []; //  a large array containing values... not shown.
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'cgi-bin/datagen.cgi',
  data: { "id:: 1, "params":  Params },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function( db ){ console.log( "done" ); }
});`

I like the ease of using `$.ajax(...` to POST a lot of json data to a script, but I don't see a way to switch to Server Sent Event messaging to receive (listen) for return data.
Using SSE instead of ajax, I don't see (and can't find an example) of POSTing a lot of data to the script.

I can't (yet) use Websockets either - so SSE is really my only choice.

-AC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, SSE does not support POST data. This is an annoying oversight in the standard; especially given that the browsers typically just implement `EventSource` as a variation of `XMLHttpRequest`, which already does allow POST.

One (messy) option is to have your cgi write its progress to a log file, and then write a SSE server script that polls that log file. You'll have two sockets open to the server, one for the ajax call, one for the SSE. Yuk.

The better option is to use the long-poll (also called comet) approach. You need to use the `XMLHttpRequest` object directly, instead of jQuery's `$.ajax()`, but it is not so bad. The advantage is that (on most browsers) you get what you want to do for free, as your xhr object is having `onreadystatechange()` called with all that progress information your back-end script is sending. You can tell the difference between progress information and the final result by looking at `xhr.readyState`: 3 means it is in progress, 4 means it is done.

Check out chapter 7 of HTML5 Data Push Apps with SSE (O'Reilly) for more explanation (Disclaimer: my book), or you'll find plenty of information on the web. Chapter 9, on authentication, is where I moan about the lack of POST support in SSE, and show how to add workarounds to the application that was built-up in earlier chapters.